# Dynamically Link To Latest 'jar-with-dependencies' From Maven Central

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, maven-central

I'm trying to use the [Maven central API](http://search.maven.org/#api) to provide dynamic download links for the latest versions of an artifact. While this works for a normal jar, I cannot seem to get it to link to the 'jar-with-dependencies' version of the artifact.

Using the `com.ning:nagios` artifact, the latest can be downloaded at

http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.ning&a=nagios&v=LATEST

I had *assumed* that I could use the `l` query param (based on the linked API) to specify the 'jar-with-dependencies' classifier but the link only downloads the normal jar.

http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.ning&a=nagios&v=LATEST&l=jar-with-dependencies

Is there any way to link to this version of the artifact?

Comment: I still don't understand why somebody down-voted this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the classifier parameter is `'c'` for the redirecting download service, not `'l'` as used in the Solr API (in that API `'c'` is for 'classname') - so this will work:

https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.ning&a=nagios&v=LATEST&c=jar-with-dependencies

*(note, **updated** after [Sonatype put BASIC auth on the old url](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/540439217600360448) - we use this new official download url on maven.org instead now)*

It downloads the 1.2MB jar that includes dependencies (not the regular jar) - currently the latest version is `nagios-0.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Comment: Ugh I should have known to just try that. I blame lack of sleep. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to link to a dependency like this without hitting the basic auth?